# Apache says it can't read htaccess file when accessing files under specific folder

Tags: web-server, apache-2.4, .htaccess, file-permissions

For other folders, my `.htaccess` file works fine, but when I was trying to download files under `files` folder, I got an error saying

```
You don't have permission to access /files/ on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
Apache/2.4.18 (Debian) Server at example.com Port
```

I checked the permission settings of related files, didn't find anything wrong, and `.htaccess` is world readable under `/var/www/html/`. Plus, `files` folder is world readable too.

When I `ls -l` with low privileged user, I get

```
ls: cannot access 'files/ImmunityDebugger_1_85_setup.exe': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'files/lwk69ff8f3169e274429c': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'files/openwrt-ramips-mt7620a-hc5861-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'files/ssss.sh': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'files/sss.tmpl': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'files/to.torrent': Permission denied
```

And with root privilege

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1945064624 Apr  6 03:04 10_y
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    3528192 Aug  2  2012 anyconnect-win-3.0.3054-pre-deploy-k9.msi
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user       3238 Apr  9 08:05 bap.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user       1115 May 27 11:45 car
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    9379014 May  8 08:22 taaa.pdf
```

Comment: I tried deleting the `files` folder using normal user and failed, due to insufficient privilege... but when I `ls -l files`, all I see is the files are owned by my current user (at least looks like so), and the `files` folder itself is also owned by my current user.

Comment: Which OS? Anything like SElinux enabled? Please show output of these ls -l commands.

Comment: @JayMcTee I am using Debian Stretch

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365981/server-unable-to-read-htaccess-file-denying-access-to-be-safe and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303895/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server-server-unable-to ?

Comment: @JayMcTee I tried with `chmod 644 *` and `chown -R user *`, didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted `files` folder and created a new one in my web root, then copied all files to the new folder, now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the permissions on the files directory. World needs to have the execute permission set to be able to traverse into it. You can set this with `chmod o+x files` from within the appropriate directory.

Comment: Your method will probably work, though